# In PostgreSQL, how do I know when subquery applied before or after filtering?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have these SQL queries:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT 
    * ,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders 
        WHERE orders.customer_id = customers.id
    ) as orders_count
FROM customers
LIMIT 10
```

The execution plan for this query:

[image]

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT 
    * ,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders 
        WHERE orders.customer_id = customers.id
    ) as orders_count
FROM customers
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 10
```

The execution plan for this query:

[image]

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT 
    * ,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders 
        WHERE orders.customer_id = customers.id
    ) as orders_count
FROM customers
ORDER BY orders_count
LIMIT 10
```

The execution plan for this query:

[image]

How can you know from these queries and execution plans **when the subquery "orders_count" is computed and assigned to each row in the table, and when it is restricted to only the top 10 rows**?

Given a large number of records in the customers table, I aim to annotate as few rows as possible, rather than annotating all millions of records.

Comment: You can see that the "Index Only Scan" in the SubPlan 1 (the subquery) only matches 10 rows. This means it occurs _after_ the `LIMIT 10`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. So does it mean that for each query all 3 queries the same action algorithm is applied?:
1. - 10 customer records are fetched.
2. - Only these 10 records annotated.

However, in the third query, where the ordering depends on the orders_count, doesn't PostgreSQL need to know this value (orders_count) for each record in the customers table to perform the ordering? Thus, doesn't it have to execute a subquery as many times as there are rows in customers table?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the explain plan, on line 5 (or 8 for the last one) it shows rows=10, so it looks like the SQL planner was able to use the limit in the subquery.  We can't see the number of loops on that line, though, so that's not definitive.

The third one, however, shows on line 7 that aggregating it is taking 10000 loops.  Since the order requires the sub-query, there isn't a way to limit it without calculating it for the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

In all three queries the *scalar subquery*:

```sql
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders 
  WHERE orders.customer_id = customers.id
) as orders_count
```

is defined as *correlated* to the main query.

In the first two cases, the optimizer does not need this value in the main query so it's only computed for the 10 rows that are finally selected.

In the last case this value is needed to sort the rows and then to limit them. This subquery will me computed for each row (all millions of them), each time the query is executed. You can see that by the "Limit" operator being applied only after the "Sort" operator. It's its parent.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't catch one this, could you please clear up this: **"Limit" operator being applied only after the "Sort" operator. It's its parent.** As I see in each of 3 queries, `Limit` is on the top of each query.

Comment: Limit short-circuits the execution of its children operators. That effectively reduces cost immensely for pipelined children. However, it does not reduce cost for non-pipelined ones such as "Sort". Sort is by definition materialized: this means all the sorting values need to be computed first to fully materialize the operator's dataset. Limiting happens only after; this means the engine already incurred in the cost of evaluating millions of rows, to only display 10 of them.